# Unable to update table using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

I have a data and query as below:

```
$msg = 'ABCDEFGH|AMI16025|GCIT4717730132|454627-028411|2.00|CIT|472642|03|INR|DIRECT|NA|NA|NA|31-08-2016 12:07:54|0300|NA|nitish.dola@gmail.com|09706125041|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|Success|8B4CB175614193B447959AD852B114FD709E6664FAC0566C0566B440BB8EA446';

    $splitdata          = explode('|', $msg);
    $customer_id        = $splitdata[1];

    $transaction_id     = $splitdata[2];

    $bank_id            = $splitdata[5];
    $bank_merchant_id   = $splitdata[6];

    $trans_type         = $splitdata[7];
    $pay_date           = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($splitdata[13]));

    $response_message   = '';
    $response_message   .= $splitdata[24];

    $amount_paid        = $splitdata[4];

    $bank_response_code = $splitdata[14];

    $curreny            = $splitdata[8];

    if($bank_response_code == "0300") // success trans condition
    {
        $success = true;
        //update the database
        $sql = "UPDATE ami_delegate_payments SET 
            payment_status = :payment_status, 
            amount_paid = :amount_paid,
            pay_date    = :pay_date,
            payment_type       = :payment_type,
            transaction_id     = :transaction_id,
            bank_id     = :bank_id,
            bank_merchant_id   = :bank_merchant_id,
            bank_response_code = :bank_response_code,
            bank_message       = :msg,
            curreny     = :curreny
            WHERE customer_id = :customer_id";

        $pdo->beginTransaction();
        try {                          
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        $payment_status = 1;

        $stmt->bindParam(':payment_status', $payment_status, PDO::PARAM_STR);                                               
        $stmt->bindParam(':amount_paid', $amount_paid, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':pay_date', $pay_date, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':payment_type', $payment_type, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':transaction_id', $transaction_id, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':bank_id', $bank_id, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':bank_merchant_id', $bank_merchant_id, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':bank_response_code', $bank_response_code, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':msg', $msg, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':curreny', $curreny, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt->bindParam(':customer_id', $customer_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);         
        $stmt->execute();
        var_dump($stmt->debugDumpParams);
        if($stmt->rowCount()) {
          echo 'Added';
        }else{
          echo 'No';
        }
        exit;
    }catch (PDOException $e) {
        var_dump($e); exit;
    }
```

Tghough I am always getting output as

`NULLED Added`

the data is not updated actually ! Whats wrong . The customer id `AMI16025` exists in database

Comment: Have you set PDO to Exception Mode anywhere? If not, you'll have to manually check the error message after you execute your query

Comment: I don't see commit()

Answer (score 0):

you call `beginTransaction()`but don't `commit()`so PDO automatically does a `rollback()`

From manual

> if you didn't explicitly commit the transaction, then it is assumed
>   that something went awry, so the rollback is performed for the safety
>   of your data.